# Directive background not changing on click (through Event binding)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

In the following example on clicking the div, the background must change to yellow. Not happening, also no error given. Pl, explain why!

```js
//module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.name = 'Peter';
});

//directive declaration
app.directive('myStudent', function(){
 return{
  template:"<div style='width:200px;height:200px;'>Hi my friend!</div>",
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
   elem.bind('click',function(){
    elem.css("background","yellow");

   });
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

{{name}}<br/>
<my-student></my-student>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a directive from an element, you have to keep in mind that the newly created element uses thew following display type by default:

```
display: inline;
```

And thus, has a 0px height.

You can fix it by simply adding display: block; to the directive element:

```
<my-student style="display: block;"></my-student>
```

Or creating the directive using an attribute:

```
<div my-student></div>
```

Here's an updated example:

```js
//module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.name = 'Peter';
});

//directive declaration
app.directive('myStudent', function(){
 return{
  template:"<div style='width:200px;height:200px;'>Hi my friend!</div>",
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
   elem.bind('click',function(){
    elem.css("background","yellow");

   });
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

{{name}}<br/>
<my-student style="display: block;"></my-student>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

In any case, I would recommend that you stick to the angular ng-click directive for this kind of interaction, find an example below:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.name = 'Peter';
});

app.directive('myStudent', function(){
 return{
  template:"<div ng-click='changeBackground()' style='height:200px;' ng-style='divStyle'>Hi my friend!</div>",
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      scope.changeBackground = () => {
        scope.divStyle = { backgroundColor: 'yellow' }
      }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

{{name}}<br/>
<div my-student></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```